# DDK make to .sln

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, driver

Is there an tool that would convert WinDDK make to VS2010 project\solution?

Comment: No.  You could use the General + Makefile project template to call nmake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at DDKBuild.

- http://www.hollistech.com/Resources/ddkbuild/ddkbuild.htm

I use Visual Studio 2012 in combination with DDKBuild to compile drivers - when errors show up I can see them in the Error List window and can get taken straight to the right line in the driver source...saves a bunch of time!

I've set up various SolutionConfigurations for different driver options that I want e.g. running a PreFast pass, compiling as 32bit, 64bit, for different OS targets, etc - makes it super easy to switch between Release and Debug, or the static analysis tools.

Basically you create a new Visual Studio Makefile Project in Visual studio, then set the NMAKE|Build Command Line to something like this:

```
ddkbuild -WIN7 -prefast checked . -cZ
```

or

```
ddkbuild -WIN7XP checked . -cZ
```

or

```
ddkbuild -WIN7XP free . -cZ
```

etc, depending on the platform you are targeting.

I haven't used it myself, but for a more powerful way to leverage Visual Studio to do driver development, take a look at VisualDDK...it can let you develop your driver via VMWare....so that crashes just take down the virtual machine, rather than your whole machine. It also offers a way to do kernel debugging .... normally you need a secondary machine to do that (and a USB, Firewire, or Ethernet link).

- http://visualddk.sysprogs.org/